# Fetch Record of Maximum Value **(Coredata)**

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, core-data

I am new to Core Data,I am trying to fetch a record which has maximum Timestamp value.
In Following code I am getting the maximum TimeStamp value but I want that record that has maximum timestamp value.

AppDelegate *appDelegate =  (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"EnergyCumulative" inManagedObjectContext:context];


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[ NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression
                                   expressionForKeyPath:@"TimeStamp"];
NSExpression *ex = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" 
                                             arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];


NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"AvgReading"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:ex];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSStringAttributeType];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


NSError *error;  

NSArray *tripArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
 NSLog(@"%@",tripArray);
```

In NSLog I am getting
(
        {
        AvgReading = 1342704600000;
    }
)

Ex. I have Entity **EnergyCumulative** in that I have attribute **Reading** & **TimeStamp**, so I want that reading that has maximum timestamp

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of your `TimeStamp`?

Change the type of

```
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSStringAttributeType];
```

to `NSDateAttributeType` in case it is a Date type, or `NSDecimalAttributeType` in case it is a Number.

By the way, you've wrote `[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];` two times... (well, not a big deal)

---

#### EDIT:

You can use

```
[[tripArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"AvgReading"];
```

to get your max timestamp. ('@AvgReading' is not a good name I think, though it well work)

(You can get the max timestamp just use Use `NSStringAttributeType`??)

Comment: I want that row which has maximum TimeStamp value. currently I am getting only maximum TimeStamp value

Comment: Ex. I have Entity in that I have attribute Reading, so I want that reading that has maximum timestamp.

Comment: @Rupesh Please make sure that the `TimeStamp` in `...expressionForKeyPath:@"TimeStamp"` is a attribute in your model..

Comment: Yes I have attribute TimeStamp in my coredata model

Comment: @Rupesh I just notice that attribute of CoreData's model cannot be a name with upper case! So `TimeStamp` must not a attribute. If it is `timeStamp`, you need to replace it in `...expressionForKeyPath:@"TimeStamp"` either.

Comment: kjuly :I was able to set the attribute name with Upper Case. I think its a bug of Xcode.

Comment: Using Upper case attribute its not a problem for me, problem is preparing a query such that i can have record/entire row. which have maximum timestamp ie highest value.